# Smallest and largest of five inputs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am in a class trying to work on the problem, of taking five inputs and giving the smallest and largest. I have some code wrote up but it doesn't work and I cannot see why. Any help would be great. Can someone point me in the wrong direction. I can write in the inputs and but when it gives me a output both largest and smallest show up as `NaN`.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title> 6.20 Homework </title>
        <script type = "text/javascript">

        var i1, i2, i3, i4, i5; //input numbers
        var largest; 
        var smallest; //largest and smallest

        i1=window.prompt ("Please enter first integer","0");
        i2=window.prompt ("Please enter second integer","0");
        i3=window.prompt ("Please enter third integer","0");
        i4=window.prompt ("Please enter fourth integer","0");
        i5=window.prompt ("Please enter fifth integer","0");

        i1 = largest;
        i1 = smallest;


        if ( i2 > largest )
            { i2 = largest}

        if ( i3 > largest )
            { i3 = largest}

        if ( i4 > largest )
            {i4 = largest} 

        if ( i5 > largest )
            { i5 = largest}



        if (i2 < smallest )
            {i2 = smallest}

        if (i3 < smallest )
            {i3 = smallest}

        if (i4 < smallest )
            {i4 = smallest}

        if (i5 < smallest )
            {i5 = smallest}

        document.writeln(+largest+ " is the largest");
        document.writeln(+smallest+ " is the smallest");
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `if` statements, you can use [`Math.max()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp) and [`Math.min()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_min.asp):

```
var largest = Math.max(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5);
var smallest = Math.min(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5);
```

Comment: Can't use math as it is only what is in the section, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Change all = operations to opposite ones, like this: `smallest = i1;`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.use `Math.max` and `Math.min` for finding largest ans smallest numbers respectively.

```js
        var i1, i2, i3, i4, i5; //input numbers
        var largest; 
        var smallest; //largest and smallest

        i1=window.prompt ("Please enter first integer","0");
        i2=window.prompt ("Please enter second integer","0");
        i3=window.prompt ("Please enter third integer","0");
        i4=window.prompt ("Please enter fourth integer","0");
        i5=window.prompt ("Please enter fifth integer","0");
       
       largest =  Math.max(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5);
       smallest = Math.min(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5);
       console.log(largest);
       console.log(smallest);
```

Answer (score 0):

on every line that looks like this: `i1 = largest;` you are changing the value of the integer and not the value of `largest` or `smallest` you should switch the order there: `largest = i1`

Answer (score -1):

I would probably suggest you to first create an array and an insert function which inserts the inputs into the array. By doing that , every time you get an input you insert the number in the right place of the array. Like :

```
var insert = function(arr,inp){
  if(arr.length == 0) { arr.push(inp); return; }
  var inserted = false;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] > inp){
     var temp = arr[i];
     arr[i] = inp;
     insert(arr,temp);
     return;
    }
  }
  arr.push(inp);
}

var inputs;                //array to insert inputs
var i1, i2, i3, i4, i5; //input numbers

i1=window.prompt ("Please enter first integer","0");
insert(inputs,i1);
i2=window.prompt ("Please enter second integer","0");
insert(inputs,i2);
i3=window.prompt ("Please enter third integer","0");
insert(inputs,i3);
i4=window.prompt ("Please enter fourth integer","0");
insert(inputs,i4);
i5=window.prompt ("Please enter fifth integer","0");
insert(inputs,i5);

document.writeln(+inputs[inputs.length-1]+ " is the largest");
document.writeln(+inputs[0]+ " is the smallest");
```